# Matlab estimateUncalibratedRectification function for column rectification

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, stereo-3d, matlab-cvst

Can I somehow use estimateUncalibratedRectification function from Stereo Vision toolbox in Matlab to rectify images in such a way that corresponding points will appear on the same columns?

From demo Stereo Image Rectification it seems to do only row rectification. I tried to flip x and y in such a way:

```
F = estimateFundamentalMatrix(fliplr(features1), fliplr(features2), 'Method', 'Norm8Point');
[T1, T2] = estimateUncalibratedRectification(F, fliplr(features1), fliplr(features2), size(image1));
T1 = flipXY(T1);
T2 = flipXY(T2);
```

where

```
function newT = flipXY(T)
   newT = [T(2, 2), T(2, 1), T(2, 3); ...
           T(1, 2), T(1, 1), T(1, 3); ...
           T(3, 2), T(3, 1), T(3, 3)];
end
```

but it seems not work.